# Управление тачпадом в терминале на линуксе

Tags: linux, ubuntu, консоль, kde

Подскажите, пожалуйста, команду или скрипт, как включить/выключить тачпад на линуксе в консольке. Ubuntu, KDE 5, гугл не дал ответа, спрашивал его много раз :)

Comment: Учимся гуглить вместе с @KoVadim https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/531866/how-can-i-disable-an-input-device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первая ссылка в поисковике - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/388963/how-can-i-enable-disable-the-synaptics-touchpad-in-debian-9-with-libinput

```
synclient TouchpadOff=1 # заблокировать


synclient TouchpadOff=0  # разблокировать
```

Если же такого нет, тогда наверно будет xinput

```
xinput set-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Device Enabled" 0  # заблокировать

xinput set-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Device Enabled" 1 # разблокировать
```

Comment: только если татч через синаптик работает... сейчас libinput в моде — там ЕМНИП xinput'ом как и всё прочие устройства дёргают (подразумевая, что дело всё ещё на иксах)...

Comment: Первое не работало, помогло второе. Но ещё `xinput list | grep -i "touchpad"` нужно, чтобы узнать название и передать `xinput`-у.

Comment: Также `xinput enable`-`xinput disable` работает.